# The templates had the following errors when running

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, t4, strongly-typed-view

When I try to add a strongly typed view in ASP.NET MVC 3, I get the following error:

[image: The templates had the following 4 errors when running]

I restarted Visual studio, rebuild the project, tried again to add a view and got the following:
[image: The templates had the following 2 errors when running]

My model:

```
public class SimpleModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return View(new SimpleModel());
    }
}
```

The problem is environment-wide (I created a new project and tried to add a view, same result) and is not solved by restarting Visual studio or my development machine.
Edit: Simply reinstalling ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 solved the problem.

Comment: Are both `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` and `System.Core.dll` added as references to the project?

Comment: @RobH System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations is referenced, but System.Core is not. When I try to add it manually, I get the following error: A reference to 'System.Core' cannot be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system.

Comment: looks like visual studio can't access System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll, could you install it into GAC?

Comment: Or I think you could use ProcessMonitor to find out where exactly visual studio tries to search for that dll.

Answer (score 0):

Using [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), I've found, that at least on my machine, Visual Studio loads `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` from GAC:

> 12:43:12.6470833 PM   devenv.exe  772 Load Image  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll   SUCCESS Image Base: 0x5f7b0000, Image Size: 0x1e000

What I did was I've started process monitor, add filter to capture events only from devenv.exe, then tried to scaffold view for MVC 3 application, then searched in captured events for `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll`

Comment: I did what you describe, and I got "PATH NOT FOUND" for
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll 
    and "SUCCESS" for C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll

Comment: Try to search further, I see that it loads from different locations too, like C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll